material mui snackbar force auto hide on mouse over
I have the following snackbar implementation from the material UI library
    <Snackbar
      open={isOpen}
      transitionDuration={{ enter: 500, exit: 500 }}
      TransitionComponent={Slide}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      onClose={() => {
        setShowToast(false);
      }}
      ClickAwayListenerProps={{ mouseEvent: false }}
    >
...content
</Snackbar/>

How can I force the snackbar to hide after the hideDuration and when the mouse is over the snackbar??
